# Macro Refresh and Remove Duplicate issue

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, refresh

I am trying to set up a macro that refreshes the data then removes the duplicates but when i set one up the duplicates do not remove.

```
Sub Update()
'
' Update Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveSheet.Range("Table_MHE_Failure_Reporting.accdb4[#All]").RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

I tried to use call and have it as 2 seprate macros but the same issue came up so i dont know what to do

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, following the refresh, there actually are duplicates in the 2nd column of the specified range of cells then the most likely problem is that `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` doesn't 'wait' for completion for 'background queries' (see the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.refreshall)) i.e. the following line to remove duplicates will be executed immediately and (highly likely) long before the refresh has completed.

The solution is to add this line

```
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

After the `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` line and before the subsequent line to remove the duplicates. With this line, all queries are executed before code continues running.